# How to manipulate jquery autocomplete plugin to get both the id and the value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

Im using this jquery autocomplete plugin. The data format for autocomplete  is like the following

```
"name"=>"1" format.
```

Im just showing the name of the product in my drop down list and it is very insecure to show the id of the product. But when I submit I need the id of the product selected. For this Im trying to give an attribute to the input text field like this

```
input type='text' name='product' productid=''
```

Now when user selects any product, productid attribute should get this value. How to go about this

Comment: Have you had a look at the [Custom data and display](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data) example in the jQueryUI docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're after is the `select` option.

Let's say your data source is the following array of objects:

```
var data = [
    {
        label: 'Product 1',
        productid: '1'
    },
    {
        label: 'Product 2',
        productid: '2'
    },{
        label: 'Product 3',
        productid: '1'
    }];
```

By default the plugin will look for the **label** and **value** property in your object (if the "value" is missing, it will use the "label").

**Note**: that if you provide a value, it will be used to set the value of the input when you select a suggested item in the menu !

So our example, the property `productid` will actually not be used by directly the plugin, it does not know about it, but we will have access to it in the event handlers parameter `ui.item`.

What I would do is add an hidden field to store the actual selected value (and not the attribute "productid" like you suggest in your question).

```
<input type="hidden" id="productid" value="" />
```

The js code:

```
$("#myinput").autocomplete({
    source: data,
    // the 'select' event is triggered when an item is selected in the menu
    select: function(e, ui) {
        $("#productid").val(ui.item.productid);
        // if you want to add the "productid" attiubte
        $(this).attr('productid', ui.item.productid);
    }
});
```

**Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/4SbhW/)**

Comment: Actually I'm using another plugin, the link to which is this         http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/      But I worked on the same lines and made it work. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Actually, the plugin from bassistance is now the jQuery UI Autocomplete widget :-)